Multiple instances of same service accessing external service
I have following question :
There is service MyService (with REST API written asp.net core ) calling some external service ExtS . Based on the call of ExtS some table on DB ( SQL based ) is updated.
There is possible that more than 1 instances of MyService is running. But all instances access same DB. What is preferred method to ensure that 2 (or more) instances will not update same record in the DB after call of ExtS ? As I understand there locking mechanism on DB to prevent multiple updates simultaneously but I am not sure that it is enough
UPD:
Here are more details
DB is SqlServer 2022
This code is part of MyService :
using System;
public class TransactionsCoordinator
{
    IExternalService _extrenalService; //provided by dependency injection
    

    public async Task HandleTransaction(MyItemDTO  itemToHandle)
    {
        itemToHandle.HandleStatus = TransactionStatus.INPROCESS;
        UpdateItem(itemToHandle); //Update in DB 

        try
        {
            var valueFromItem = GetValueForItem(itemToHandle);
            var externalStatus = await SendValueToService(valueFromItem, itemToHandle);
            if (externalStatus == ExternternalStatus.Success)
            {
                //Some more updates
                itemToHandle.HandleStatus = TransactionStatus.SUCCESS;
            }
            else
            {
                itemToHandle.HandleStatus = TransactionStatus.FAILED;
            }
            UpdateItem(itemToHandle);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            itemToHandle.HandleStatus = TransactionStatus.FAILED;
            UpdateItem(itemToHandle);
        }
    }

    private decimal GetValueForItem(MyItemDTO itemToHandle)
    {
        decimal result;
        //based on fields of itemToHandle - get result....
        return result;
    }

    async private Task<ExternternalStatus> SendValueToService(decimal valueToSend, MyItemDTO itemToHandle)
    {
        //_externalService - send rest call to URL of the external service ExtS
        var serviceResult = await _externalService.SendValue(valueToSend, itemToHandle.someField);
        return serviceResult;
    }
} 

transaction obtainded from DB by other class as following :
//......
private async Task HandleTransactionAsync()
{
    var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    //Get item with latest update date with status != inprocess and success 
    var myItemDTO = _myItemsService.GetItemToHandle(currentTime); 
    if (myItemDTO != null)
    {
        _transactionsCoordinator.HandleTransaction(myItemDTO);
    }
}

Thanks in advance

"As I understand there locking mechanism on DB to prevent multiple updates simultaneously but I am not sure that it is enough" - yes there is, also you can use transactions to enforce consistency if there some reads involved. Other than that  - you will need to provide a little bit more details (database used, queries, possibly some [mre]/code) and why exactly you have doubts about the consistency in this case.

Added more details

In my humble opinion, locking mechanism is designed for consistency, no matter row lock/table lock/database lock. Even if there're 2 requests send at the same time, they always be handled from  the first to the end, I mean there is always a request being handled at first and it will get the lock, and the second request will wait in most of the scenarios. To make sure about the consistency, maybe we can use Message queue. In the meantime, do we face any issue right now? Maybe the concurrency is not as high as expected.

Thanks for replies - I added also usage of MQ
